# Flow charting a philosophical argument

Tags: debate

Is there a method, which is used, to write a philosophical argument so that each point and logical consequence is clearer than if the argument were written out in paragraph form, such as an outline or flow chart?

Comment: What have you found so far, what exactly are you looking for an explanation about? (You may wish to review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_map)

Comment: I've looked but haven't really found much. An argument map however might be exactly what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

If we're strictly talking about formal logic, you could have a look at [analytic tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). These are graphical representations of logical expressions that can be used to determine their correctness (see image below).

There are also different variants, like Fitch style and others.

[image]

Comment: I'm more trying to figure out a way to draw out an argument that would make it more difficult for a person to sidestep it using some non argument, but I guess if a person is going to reject a discussion then they'll do it no matter what.